# Trying to build VERY SIMPLE WEB SERVER in java and it freezes

Tags: java, webserver

I'm trying to build a VERY simple web server.  I got it to work. Right now I use an `InputStream` and stop at the end of the first line.  I figured I could stop when a -1 is returned (since that would be the end of the stream) but it freezes. Why?

```
connection=server.accept();
OutputStream out=new BufferedOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() ); 
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream( connection.getInputStream() );

// read in one line
StringBuffer request = new StringBuffer(1000);
System.out.println("get connection reading in data \r");
while(true)
{
  int c=in.read();
  //  if (c=='\r') break;
  if (c==-1) break;
  request.append((char)c);
}
System.out.println(request);
```

Comment: reading one character at a time will be slow... I'd wrap a BufferedInputStream around the socket's input stream and use readLine to read one line at a time.

Comment: I'm sure this should be in meta, but why do we have to wait for approvals for edits?  Especially source code formatting edits that GREATLY IMPROVE THE READABILITY of the question?

Answer (score 3):

You're waiting for the client to close its connection - it's not going to do that, because it's waiting for the response!

You need to read the request and work out when it's completed based on the headers.